# How to compare values between a 2 dimensional and one dimesional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Array1:
[[P01, 153425], [P02, 3951990], [P03, 106658], [P04, 4563594], [P05, 60198], [P07, 326292], [P08, 1265], [P09, 108293], [P10, 183698], [P11, 5084]] this comes from BigQuery.

Array2: 
[[P01], [P02], [P03], [P04], [P05], [P06], [P07], [P08], [P09], [P10], [P11]]
this array is fetched from google sheet column using sheet.getSheetValues(3,1,11,1);

Based on this i should update a column in google sheet based on the matching values between Array1 and Array2:
eg: [153425,3951990,106658,4563594,60198,326292,1265,108293,183698,5084]

if value does not match the corresponding value should remain empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare `Array1[i][0]` with `Array2[j]` inside `for` loop, if it is equal take the value of `Array1[i][1]`

```
for(var i=0; i<Array1.length; i++){
   for(var j=0; j<Array2.length; j++){
      if(Array1[i][0] == Array2[j]){
         //do something
         //if it can be equal to only one number, you can break it here
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

Then you should compare `Array2[i]` with  `Array1[j][0]`

```
for(var i=0; i<Array2.length; i++){
   var isExist = false;
   for(var j=0; j<Array1.length; j++){
      if(Array2[i] == Array1[j][0]){
         //do something
         //if it can be equal to only one number, you can break it here
         isExist = true;
      }
   }
   if(!isExist){
     //do something if it does not exist
   }
}
```

Comment: i get only the first five values [153425, 3951990, 106658, 4563594, 60198].i think this is because P06 value is not present in the Array1.

Comment: @ashwin0230 Sorry, my first answer was incorrect. Now, I have edited it. Actually, you need second `for` loop inside first, so that you could compare value of first loop for each value of second.

Comment: thankyou @kzharas210,,,,i get all the values now.but i face a small issue.since P06 value does not match it should be updated as null or empty in that index in the resultant array.